# How to do a linear interpolation in pandas taking values of X into account?

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I have a data-frame with two columns: `X` and `Y`. Some of the values in `Y` are missing (`np.nan`).

I would like to fill the `NaNs` using a linear interpolation. In more details, I want to order the data frame by `X` and any missing values of `Y` should be a "linear mixture" of the two neighbouring values of `Y` (one corresponding to smaller `X` and another one to larger `X`).

If the value of `X` corresponding to a missing `Y` is closer to one of the two `X` with available `Y`, then the filled value of `Y` should be close to the corresponding `Y`. How to do it efficiently and elegantly in pandas?

Please note, that `pandas.Series.interpolate` does not do what I need, as far as I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up a dataframe:

```
x = [0,1,3,4,7,9,11,122,123,128]
y = [2,8,12,np.NaN, 22, 31, 34, np.NaN, 43, 48]

df = pd.DataFrame({"x":x, "y":y})
print(df)

     x     y
0    0   2.0
1    1   8.0
2    3  12.0
3    4   NaN
4    7  22.0
5    9  31.0
6   11  34.0
7  122   NaN
8  123  43.0
9  128  48.0
```

Set column 'x' to the index:

```
df = df.set_index('x')
```

Then set the method in the interplote to 'index'.

```
df.y = df.y.interpolate(method='index')
```

This results in:

```
df

        y
x   
0      2.000000
1      8.000000
3     12.000000
4     14.500000
7     22.000000
9     31.000000
11    34.000000
122   42.919643
123   43.000000
128   48.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Method : Linear

limit_direction = Both : Will cover your first and last rows for filling

limit = total number of nan to be replaced. check the % of nan of the total searies and then you can decide what's the best Limit.

```
df['column_Name'] = df['column_Name'].interpolate(
                        method='linear', limit_direction='both', limit=45)
```